# Update Model without Dynamic attributes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use the below code in my Product model to add dynamic attributes from related models:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    parent::booted();

    static::retrieved(function ($entity) {
        foreach ($entity->attributes()->get() as $attribute) {
            $entity->attributes[$attribute->code] = $attribute->eav->value->value;
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to update the original model attributes in ProductController:

```
$updated = $product->update($request->validated());
```

I get an error because this code also try to update dynamic attributes on Product model.
I searched in the code and I found an `getOriginal()` method but this returns an array and not an eloquent model.

### UPDATE

I temporarly resolved unsetting dynamic attributes before saving

```
static::saving(function ($entity) {
    foreach ($entity->attributes()->get() as $attribute) {
        unset($entity->attributes[$attribute->code]);
    }
});
```

Comment: cant you just use `$entity->attributes->map(...)` where you need this structure?

Comment: ->map works on collections, I need to remove some attributes from model